# Sabre Create Passenger Record : Authorization failed due to no access privileges

Tags: rest, sabre

I am trying to use the sabre api for creating a booking (`CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ`) using the testing credentials, but I am always getting the following error message:

```
{
  "status": "NotProcessed",
  "type": "Validation",
  "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.SEC.NOT_AUTHORIZED",
  "timeStamp": "2017-01-19T20:56:23.861-06:00",
  "message": "Authorization failed due to no access privileges"
}
```

Anyone knows if these testing credentials allow to book fights in testing environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it makes sense that the API does not work with test credentials since the PNR created would be saved into a PCC which you do not have with DEVCENTER credentials.

The target audience for the API seems to suggest the same:

> Target Audience: All Sabre APIs Customers

I'd suggest you to use the 'Become a Sabre customer' form in DevStudio in order to request access to the same.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this and needed to supply an additional query parameter `?mode=create` to the endpoint. I was using:

`https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.2.0/passenger/records`

but needed:

`https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v2.2.0/passenger/records?mode=create`

Unfortunately, the Sabre documentation is not clear about the values you can supply for the mode parameter and though it says mode is required, as of this writing the description reads:

```
Pass an optional search string for looking up inventory
```

So on one-hand the documentation says required, on the other hand, it says optional. Typical Sabre. I have requested their support staff resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and obtained a response from Sabre support for the same. Turns out you'll need a PCC code in order to use `CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ` API. It is a prerequisite as mentioned in the document [here](https://beta.developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/onboarding/sabre-universe).

[image: Response from Sabre]

**Solution**

1. Obtain PCC code from Sabre.
2. Go to your user profile in Sabre Dev Studio.
3. Edit your profile and add the PCC code in the corresponding column.